# how to check authentication of username and password for mail in java?

Tags: java, email

I need to authenticate user-name and password of user on entering his credentials and alert him if  authentication fails . and check authentication every time before sending a mail.

Comment: in which mail server? Gmail? Exchange Server? Your question is too broad.

Comment: I need to use smtp to send mail and check authentication of user  before sending mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look into `javax.mail.*` API for your job. See this references for more details :

1) http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

2) http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#JavaMailIntro